# Marklogic - How to specify collection name externally in Java POJO (using spring JPA repository)

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, marklogic

I am new to Marklogic and want to specify collection name externally in Java POJO. Currently spring JPA repository tries to search for collection with name as class name of pojo.

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends MarkLogicRepository<Person, String> {
}
```

```
public class Person {

    @Id
    private String personId;

    private String personName;

}
```

So in above example, spring fetched data from "Person" collection which is fine for my local development. But for Dev and Test servers, I need to fetch data from versioned collection like "Person_V1"/ "Person_V2" which can be configured in application.properties file.
How can I make collection name configurable?

Answer (score 0):

> It is worth noting that MarkLogic `collection` is one of the document metadata categories. It is non-hierarchical and version|class-independent.

> Seems to me you first attempt to map `entity` POJO to define `collection` which requires marshalling.  The `Annotation` will be something like:

```
    @Document(
            uri = "/person_{version}/${GUID}.xml",
            collectionPrefix = "{collection-prefix|null}",
            collection = "${method.getName()}"
    )
```

> 2ndly, you said you wish to cconfigure the `collection` in `application.properties`. Then the `.properties` file looks like this:

```
# prefix could be `Person_V1`, ` Person_V2` or null
person.collectionPrefix =   
person.collection =
```

You can define the `Annotation` in the main class like:

```
    @Value("${person.collectionPrefix}")
    private String ***;
    @Value("${person.collection}")
    private String ***;
```

> The optimised MarkLogic Java document operation boils down to:

```
  metadata(Handle).getCollections().add(All)("{collection-array}");
```

What gives you the leeway, though, is to define POJO object as `args` in method to `setCollections() | getCollections()`.

A full review of MarkLogic `metadata` Class and Method is:

```
https://docs.marklogic.com/javadoc/client/com/marklogic/client/io/DocumentMetadataHandle.html
```